# How do you use the particleground plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, installation, jsbin

I believe I've done everything right; I followed the instructions. Could you show me what I'm missing please?

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xiripu/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your js include for particle needs to follow this <script src="path/to/jquery.particleground.min.js"></script>, on jsbin I'm fairly certain <script src="jquery.particleground.js"></script> isn't enough

Comment: thanks a lot for that, put me on the right direction. Finally got it working!